# Edge, turn off MEDIA12598 Independent Composition warning

Tags: microsoft-edge

We are using FileReader, readAsDataURL to load a large video into the browser (Edge).  It takes a very long time to load, and then immediately after, the MEDIA12598 warning shows in the console, and logs entire base 64 encoded data object, which is huge.  Is there a way to turn this warning off before loading the video?  Or, is there a fix?  Why is Independent Composition turned off?

Comment: I believe you're looking for the `microsoft-edge` tag instead, if your question is about the Edge browser.